# Date in textbox changes after submitting form

Tags: javascript, jsp, date

I have a JSP in which there's a form. One of the fields in this form is a textbox where I accept a date. I have a calender from which user cans elect a date. Now, when the user selects the date it appears in the textbox in "dd-mm-yyyy" format. (ex : 11-06-2012)

As soon as the form is submitted it changes to long (ex : Mon Jun 11 00:00:00 IST 2012)
Now if any more search criteria is added, then it throws an error as the date isn't validated.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Code given below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function formDateValidate() {
    var flag = 0;
    var message = "";

    if (document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionFromDate.value != ""
            || document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionToDate.value != ""
            || document.searchTemporaryPromotion.softwarePartNumber.value != "") {
        document.searchTemporaryPromotion.resolve.value = "";
    }
    printMessageForDiv(new Array("dateLabel"), new Array(""));

    if (document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionFromDate.value != "") {
        var result1 = validateDate(document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionFromDate);

        if (result1 != "") {
            message = message
                    + "Check From Date: "
                    + result1
                    + " You entered: "
                    + document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionFromDate.value
                    + ".<br>";
            printMessageForDiv(
                    new Array("dateLabel", "fromDateLabelField"),
                    new Array(
                            message,
                            "<font color='red'><b>"
                                    + '*<spring:message code="label.temporaryPromotion.fromDate" />:*'
                                    + "</b></font>"));
            ++flag;
        }
    }

    if (document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionToDate.value != "") {
        var result2 = validateDate(document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionToDate);

        if (result2 != "") {
            message = message
                    + "Check To Date: "
                    + result2
                    + " You entered: "
                    + document.searchTemporaryPromotion.tempPromotionToDate.value
                    + ".<br>";
            printMessageForDiv(
                    new Array("dateLabel", "toDateLabelField"),
                    new Array(
                            message,
                            "<font color='red'><b>"
                                    + '*<spring:message code="label.temporaryPromotion.toDate" />:*'
                                    + "</b></font>"));
            ++flag;
        }
    }

    if (flag != 0) {
        document.getElementById("entireViewForSearch").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}


</script>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>temporaryPromotion</title>
</head>
<body>
<span id="dateLabel" class="errordiv"></span>
<span id="muidFieldLabel" class="errordiv"> </span>
<form:form id="searchTemporaryPromotion"
    name="searchTemporaryPromotion"
    commandName="searchTemporaryPromotionCommand" onsubmit="return checkFormOnSearch(this);">       
    <form:hidden path="currentPage" />
    <form:hidden path="usePaging" />
    <form:hidden path="itemsPerPage" />
    <form:hidden path="action" />
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none"></div>
    <p>
        <i><font color="red">*Note: Date format should be
                dd-MM-yyyy.</font> </i>
    </p>
    <spring:hasBindErrors name="searchTemporaryPromotionCommand">
        <p>
            <b><form:errors cssStyle="color: red;"></form:errors> </b>
        </p>
    </spring:hasBindErrors>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px">Search
                Criteria</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><span id="fromDateLabelField"><spring:message
                        code="label.reporting.searchTemporaryPromotion.fromDate" />:</span> <form:input
                    path="tempPromotionFromDate" id="tempPromotionFromDate"
                    cssStyle="width: 70px;text-align: center" /> <input type="button"
                value="..."
                onclick="displayCalendar(document.getElementById('tempPromotionFromDate'),'dd-mm-yyyy',this);">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span id="toDateLabelField"> <spring:message
                        code="label.reporting.searchTemporaryPromotion.toDate" />:</span> <form:input
                    path="tempPromotionToDate" id="tempPromotionToDate"
                    cssStyle="width: 70px;text-align: center" /> <input type="button"
                value="..."
                onclick="displayCalendar(document.getElementById('tempPromotionToDate'),'dd-mm-yyyy',this);">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message
                    code="label.reporting.searchTemporaryPromotion.partNumber" />: <form:input
                    path="softwarePartNumber" id="softwarePartNumber"
                    name="softwarePartNumber" cssStyle="width: 215px;" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search" onClick="javascript:onSearch();" onKeyPress="javascript:onSearch();"/>
                <input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="javascript:onClear(this);" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your validateDate() function, but I suspect it changes the original value of the input to the JS Date Object generated within the function.

Try to validate without altering the value of the input.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem but helps clear the doubts a lot! Thanks!